# TCL - read file column

Tags: file, tcl

I am trying to just put column 1 from the infile to the outfile but I am getting the whole line (outfile). How do I just put 1st column into the outfile?

Infile:

```
Game1_1000   2002.1111 1000.1111
Game2_20001  1111.2222 1122.2222
Game3_2222   1111.3333 1111.2221
```

---

Current Outfile: (not what I wanted)

```
baseball Game1_1000 2002.1111 1000.1111
baseball Game2_20001  1111.2222 1122.2222
baseball Game3_2222   1111.3333 1111.2221
```

---

I want the outfile to be like below:

```
baseball Game1_1000
baseball Game2_20001
baseball Game3_2222
```

Here is my script:

```
set infile [open "infile.txt" r]
set outfile [open "outfile.txt" w]

set lines [split [read -nonewline $infile] "\n"]
foreach line $lines {
    puts $outfile "Baseball"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script cannot give the output you say you are getting in the current outfile, it should be generating a file with `Baseball` only.

That aside, you could split the line on space and take the first element using `lindex`:

```
set infile [open "infile.txt" r]
set outfile [open "outfile.txt" w]

set lines [split [read -nonewline $infile] "\n"]
foreach line $lines {
    set columns [split $line " "]
    puts $outfile "baseball [lindex $columns 0]"
}

close $infile
close $outfile
```

Comment: This helped a lot! I had a file with 2 columns and a comma as a delimiter and I split it "," and got my columns.

Answer (score 1):

You have an input file where the individual lines are split into fields by *sequences of whitespace*. The `split` command doesn't handle that; it splits on *every* space (there are other file formats where this is the right option). Because of that, we need a different step to condition the input line into records for processing.

There are various ways of doing this. My favourite is to use `regexp` to *select all non-whitespace sequences* as words (it's got a nice short regular expression, the `\S+`):

```
set columns [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]
```

Once that's been done, you should get what you ask for from the rest of the code as you write it.

---

More complex splitting is usually best left to [the `textutil::splitx` command](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil.md) from Tcllib. The case you describe in your question is how it splits things by default, making using it extremely easy.

```
package require textutil

set columns [textutil::splitx $line]
```

Comment: There are other ways to do sophisticated text splitting; most of them have a foundation in regular expressions. They're a very powerful tool, and very easily abused.